# My gravy turned to jello overnight. How can I make it last for leftovers?

Tags: storage-method, sauce, gravy

I slow cooked a pork shoulder with some veggies (carrots, onions, celery). When it was finished, I strained out the solids and proceeded to make gravy with the liquids:

1. Start separating liquids (I used a fat separator)
2. Brown some flour
3. Add some butter and whisk until lumps are gone
4. Keep whisking and add juices (now separated, less fat) and seasoning
5. Simmer to desired thickness

The gravy was delicious that night, despite having developed a skin fairly quickly. After refrigerating it overnight, however, it was a gelatinous mess, and wouldn't melt back down.

What happened? How can I make gravy last for leftovers?

Comment: You reheated the gravy and it was *still* gelatinous?  It's normal for gravy to gel, sometimes even if the meat was boneless. See: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/9555/why-did-my-turkey-stock-turn-into-gelatin But the gelatin turns back to liquid upon reheating.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you probably used too much flour for the amount of liquid in your gravy — instead of gravy, you made pudding. You might be able to thin it down by whisking in some additional liquid such as milk or water before reheating it.

However, next time use half (or even less) percentage of flour to liquid, and you'll have better results.

Comment: Too much flour is likely the issue, but I would instead advise reheating it *first* before adding in additional liquid.  (Or, if it's really thick, adding a small amount of liquid before reheating, then thin it further as necessary once it's hot.)  Gravy is generally consumed hot, and adding liquid while it is cold may overcompensate and make the hot product too thin.

Comment: And, for liquid, consider using stock if you have it available as a thinning liquid that will also impart flavor.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted comment has the correct answer for microwave use. You have to heat it and then thin it (with stock or milk or water or whatever you want). But if you're reheating the gravy in a pot, it should suffice to just heat it sufficiently and stir/whisk it. The heat will break down the bonds formed in the fridge, and you'll be left with gravy again.

If this doesn't work, I guess thin it, but it really should :D

Answer (score 1):

How long did you cook your pork Shoulder for? 
Sometimes when you cook for a long time you will get gelatin coming of the bones and it will integrate your gravy.

It will give soups and gravy their luxurious umami, but will turn to jello once cold. I doubt this little amount of flour caused a jello texture.

Just warm it in a stovetop or microwave, and if you are like me and grossed out by the gelatinous texture, thin it with water, wine, or store brought stock.

Answer (score 1):

This means you made Great Gravy. If it gels up like that, it means you cooked the starches and properly proportioned the proteins as such to the roux. In my experience, this results in a gravy that is ungrainy when reheated.

Because gravy is just thin savory pudding.
Fight me.

You should see my mom's soup that turns into aspic when cold

Answer (score 1):

This is not unusual, I usually use 2-3 stock cubes (chicken, beef) depending on the meat in question was, add about half a cup of boiling water and whisk with the thickened gravy, this will bring it back to a good consistency.