# Australian Meat (Chunky steak) Pie: loss of Gravy/Sauce after cooling/freezing

Tags: meat, pie, gravy, australian-cuisine

**Main Question**:

When cooking the beef stew portion of the *Australian Meat (Chunky steak) Pie* recipe, the created sauce/gravy 'disappears' after cooling or freezing.

How can one prevent this from happening?

---

When the pie is baked **directly** after the stew has been completed, the pie has (almost) the desired amount of sauce/gravy.

|  |
| --- |
| [image] --- after stew has been cooked |
| [image] --- image from recipe (how it is supposed to look like) |
| [image] --- 5" pie after baking directly, after cooking the stew |

The crust (both the base and top) a is Puff pastry and the base has been pre-baked and allowed to cool before filling.

But when reheated later, there is no sauce/gravy

- 180°C (355°F) [**160°C Fan**] / Gas 3 for 15-25 minutes

When the cooked filling is allowed to set for a day (in a second attempt) in the refrigerator, the gravy is no longer fluid but more of a mass between the meat chunks. So this seems also to happen before the pie is filled.

I have been told by a Canadian friend than when a store bought pie, that is not in a tin, is warmed up does contain gravy/sauce.

---

**Secondary Question**:

- [What are the proper dimensions for a 4 or 5 inch Pie Pan?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/116082/91174)

---

**Sources**:

- [Individual Meat Pies | Australia's Best Recipes](https://www.bestrecipes.com.au/recipes/individual-meat-pies/bgt7qzur)
- [Meat Pie recipe! | RecipeTin Eats](https://www.recipetineats.com/meat-pie-recipe/)

Comment: How are you reheating it?

Comment: @TheLittlePeace 160°C Fan (added to question)

Comment: @csk if you have ideas what causes it, or what can be done, please post an answer, not a comment. See https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6533/should-users-refrain-from-answers-or-partial-answers-in-comments for a guideline which has been adopted network-wide.

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate: [https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/64143/my-gravy-turned-to-jello-overnight-how-can-i-make-it-last-for-leftovers](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/64143/my-gravy-turned-to-jello-overnight-how-can-i-make-it-last-for-leftovers)