# What are the proper dimensions for a 4 or 5 inch Pie Pan?

Tags: cookware, pie, australian-cuisine

When an Australian recipe meantions a **4 inch** or a **5 inch** pie pan, are the pans shown below what is meant?

| 4" Pie pan | 5" Pie pan |
| --- | --- |
| [image] --- 4.3"x2.9"x1.3" (10.922x7.366x3.302 cm) **volume**: 219.5728018 ml | [image] --- 4.8"x3.4"x1.2" (12.192x8.636x3.048 cm) **volume**: 262.1436955 ml |

Many recipes **assume** that everyone knows this, but I certainly did not.

Where I live such pans do not exist and are hard to come by.

---

**Sources**:

- [Individual Meat Pies | Australia's Best Recipes](https://www.bestrecipes.com.au/recipes/individual-meat-pies/bgt7qzur)
- [Meat Pie recipe! | RecipeTin Eats](https://www.recipetineats.com/meat-pie-recipe/)
- Pie Pans

  - [4" Pie pan (Webake)](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/Webake-Ruffle-Diameter-Non-Stick-Coating/dp/B08XJSP1ZX)  € 13.99
  - [5" Pie pan (Webake)](https://www.amazon.de/Mini-Pie-Pfannen-Pastetenform-antihaftbeschichtet-Backgeschirr-Sofortbacken/dp/B083M2R1WZ) € 19.84

**Disclaimer**: Other than having bought the products (listed above) myself, I have no affiliation with the product or seller.

Comment: I really don't think something like a pie dish has an absolute set of dimensions. If you google image search 5" pie dish you get everything from vertical sides to heavy flutes & a long slope.