# Isn't "bone broth" just broth?

Tags: broth

Over the last couple of years I've started hearing a lot about "bone broth." But bones and water are where all broth comes from, right? Is there a specific type of broth that's "bone broth," or is that just a new coinage to make broth sound interesting and novel?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stock vs Broth - What's the difference in usage?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/2995/stock-vs-broth-whats-the-difference-in-usage) "Bone broth" is usually just fancy marketing for stock.

Comment: I’ve noticed that many of the boxes of ‘bone broth’ sold in the store are higher calorie than other broths and stock, so it’s possible that they’ve extracted more gelatin out of the bones.  (I was looking at calories, as I had to go on an all clear diet before a medical procedure, and I think it was higher protein, too, but my memory is a bit foggy)

Comment: Is this an American thing? I think the word "broth" has a different meaning here in the UK.  To me, a broth is a kind of clear soup often with vegetables and/or meat floating in it.   The clear liquid made by extracting flavour from boiling bones is what I would call stock. If this is a pre-made concoction you can buy in cartons, maybe check the list of ingredients to be sure.

Comment: Billy: yeah, it's an American thing.  It's promoted as part of the Paleo Diet and similar trends.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's worse: bone broth is [actually stock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stock_(food)), not broth.

> Stock, sometimes called bone broth ... involves simmering animal bones, meat, seafood, or vegetables in water or wine, often for an extended period

So yes, it's completely a marketing term.

Answer (score -1):

'Bone Broth' is an actual food. I make it all the time, but I think the word ‘broth’ confuses people. The name ‘Bone Broth’ does not fit in with culinary recipe terminology so forget the term ‘broth’ when referring to bone broth. Actual ‘bone broth’ is highly nutritious, good for your microbiome (gut healing) and is used as a first food for babies. Ideally, it should be cooked low & slow for an extended period of time to extract the goodness from the bones & marrow. The time depends on the meat (ex: I cook chicken for about 12 hrs & I cook beef for about 24 hrs at just under the simmer point). It is usually cooked with some meat &/or a mirepoix in it too for flavor. It can be made with parts that most people will throw away (or turn up their noses at such as chicken feet and cow hooves &/or knuckles) but those parts are loaded with wonderful collagen. After the bone broth cools in the refrigerator, it should be gelatinous (the thicker the better). If it does not thicken, then it is just stock (or plain broth). When I cook bone broth, I reserve the first cooking for actual ‘bone broth’. I save this best quality broth for drinking. Warmed up, it is an excellent drink for first thing in the morning and is also an excellent food to break a fast with (for those of you who practice intermittent fasting). Then I will remove the initial bone broth from my pot and then recook the bones/meat for a second time. This second batch usually won’t gel up like the first initial batch and that is what I save as my ‘stock’ for soups, pilaf, & recipes (or I make ice cubes so I can add a few to a stir-fry to make a little sauce).

Comment: This seems to be a recipe for [stock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stock_(food)) - as discussed in [this question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/9555/why-did-my-turkey-stock-turn-into-gelatin), stock should gelatinize in the fridge.  Are you suggesting that bone broth is different from stock somehow, or agreeing with the other answer that they're the same thing?